# Why are the pins on the official arduino motor shield so long?

Tags: arduino, motor, driver, isolation

Here is the [Official Motor sheild](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoMotorShieldR3) website.

The shield has pin connectors at the bottom that are 2x longer than on any other shield I've seen. Why is that?

[image]

Comment: I don't know. Why don't they space the shield pins on a 100 mil interval so they will plug into a breadboard?

Comment: @PhilFrost +1 on 100 mil spacing.

Comment: @ChetanBhargava It just occurred to me: they are long so you can bend them to fit!

Comment: I probably could bend them to fit a breadboard if there were breadboards that were wider. Anyway, it's a shield so you would never put it on a breadboard anyway! Oh, and the nano DOES fit on a breadboard. I don't think the uno uses that spacing simply because breadboards aren't that wide anyway and there must be some other spacing standard.

Comment: @PhilFrost because the arduino team wanted to monetize as much as they can.

Comment: +1 on hidden monetization. You don't say that you monetize but still monetize. I don't know what is the right term to use here for arduino manufacturers.

Answer (score 6):

These are the normal stackable headers used on **OFFICIAL Arduino brand shields** (they specifically state they are used on the Proto Shields, [on the header item page](http://store.arduino.cc/ww/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=6_32&products_id=188)), and on most Adafruit shields. They even sell them as standard components (Arduino 14.5mm pin length, Adafruit 10.5mm pin length headers). This are used to stack, because normal length headers are meant to be soldered on one side, and connected on the other, flush on the board. Because they are meant to stack, you have to account for board length, plus imperfect solder joints, and component height, on the solder side.

Pricing for headers is based more on plating and pin count than it is on pin length. They would get a price break due to volume as well.

I'm guessing the others you seen haven't been official shields.

Comment: That confirms it's not a mistake but I still don't understand why. I have a bluetooth board from itead and it has a pin length of half that of motor sheild and everything lines up fine. In fact, I sandwich that in with the motor shield and it works fine. OH WAIT . . . Now I'm remembering that the bluetooth shield is strange in that the pins on the bottom don't line up with the headers on top. So maybe that's it . . there are two lengths of header pins, stubby for going just to a board and long for stacking.

Comment: @tooshel yea, itead uses both regular male headers on the bottom, then offsets the female headers on the top, one side over (about 100mils). And most of their shields arn't the full length of the arduino boards, so they don't sit on the usb-a connector or the power connector. The stubby ones have the little spacers on them and are soldered on the other side. The "Stacking" headers are all in ones, acting as both male and female headers.

Answer (score 2):

One reason could be due to high voltages present on the motor board. Slightest short could turn into flames if the shield touches any high component (like an electrolytic capacitor) on the board below. Also it could destroy the arduino in case of short.

[image]
[image]

As you can see in the above stackup that the screw terminals are only a few mm apart from the DC connector. The board is also close to the USB connector shield.

Comment: Ah, so that's how they stack up. Similar reasoning, that makes sense too - general separation of the high power stuff from the Arduino seems to be by far the most likely reason. I seem to recall a few previous questions about issues with Arduinos resetting/playing up whilst using these motor driving or relay shields.

Comment: I see that the motor shield (can't understand why these are called shields) designers have been careful to not put any exposed pads and tracks right above the USB connector shield (really a shield). Both PCB sides on the motor board are filled with logos on soldermask.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is it may be to keep any high current switching as far away from the Arduino board as possible, to reduce the risk of EMI problems.
I have never used an Arduino before though, so I may be completely wrong in my understanding of how these "shields" plug together.

Comment: That could be . . . but you'd think they would say something about it on the site. Maybe my question should be "can I clip them to normal size" . . . but then why are the long in the first place should answer that one too!

Comment: You would think so, but often "minor" technical details are skipped over in this type of product page. Since the longer pin headers are probably more expensive, it's likely there is a specific reason they have for doing this. It might be worth mailing them and asking for clarification.